# How to attach a 2-device striped mirror to a pool?

Tags: storage, zfs, zfsonlinux

I have a single-drive pool consisting of a 2TB HDD.
I have two 1TB drives I can use in mirror - I'd like to add redundancy to my pool.

How can I attach these two drives as a single device so that they can be used as a striped mirror?

Let's call my 2TB drive is `sda`, the blank 1TB drives are `sdb` and `sdc`.

I tried: `zfs attach tank sda sdb sdc` but that says `too many arguments`.

I tried: `zfs attach tank sda sdb` but that says `device is too small`

I tried: `zfs attach tank sda sdb+sdc` but that says `no such device in /dev`

I tried: `zfs attach tank sda sdb,sdc` but that says `no such device in /dev`

I've read the manual and searched the web - I am out of ideas.

I guess I could try to create a new striped pool from these two 1TB drives, create a zvol inside and use that as a mirror for my primary pool, but this is probably going to give me not enough capacity for a mirror anyway, plus a lot of unneeded overhead.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can not be directly done via ZFS. From the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?zpool(8)):

> Virtual devices cannot be nested, so a mirror or raidz virtual device
>   can only contain files or disks. Mirrors of mirrors (or other
>   combinations) are not allowed.

My suggestion is to create a new pool comprising the two 1 TB disks and use something as [syncoid](https://github.com/jimsalterjrs/sanoid) to frequently send the first pool's content to the new pool.

***--- WARNING: clunky workaround below! Do NOT use if not REALLY sure!!! ---***

Anyway, if you **really** want to add the two 1 TB disks as a mirror of the first 2 TB disks, a workaround can be tried. You can use device-mapper (in its LVM form) to concatenate the two disks and attach the resulting volume to the 2 TB device. For example:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb
pvcreate /dev/sdc
vgcreate zvg /dev/sdb
vgextend zvg /dev/sdc
lvcreate zvg --name zdev -l +100%FREE
zpool attach tank /dev/sda /dev/zvg/zdev
zpool status
```

You can achieve a similar (even better) result with mdadm, creating a RAID0 device and attaching it to the zpool:

```
mdadm --create md127 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
zpool attach tank /dev/sda /dev/md127
zpool status
```

This approach is **not** recommended. Use it at your own risk.

Comment: I want to see some of the Lego projects you built as a kid.

Comment: There's a typo: `zpool attack`. I can't correct it without performing bigger edits.

Comment: What are the risks associated with this approach? I guess my mirror could be lost from the ZFS pool - right? Can anything happen to my main 2TB disk is this configuration? I will be backing up the pool to a separate one anyway.

Comment: @unfa corrected, thanks for reporting! Regarding the risks: a) it is a clunky configuration which you need to remember when operating on you system and b) any problem with the md array *or* one of the two disks will degrade the zpool. Anyway, your 2TB disk should be safe. Sidenote: from the two approaches, I will probably choose the md-based one rather than LVM.

Comment: I'll try to go with the md solution and see how it works. Thanks!

Comment: It is resilvering and both 1TB disks are under the same write load, so it's striped - just what I wanted!

Comment: Now I have the 1+1 TB array disappear, probably the USB failed for a while. I wonder if I can restore the array in `md`, without recreating it from scratch?

Comment: Have you tried to reboot the machine? `md` should be able to automatically scan and activate the array. Otherwise, report back some information using `mdadm -E /dev/sdb; mdadm -E /dev/sdc`. Anyway, using USB disks for md/ZFS arrays is a **bad** idea.

Comment: Rebooting didn't help. Looks like md can't identify the array disks after rebooting and gparted identifies both as ZFS. So looks like it's not a USB fault, but maybe a problem with defining the array in a persistent manner. I have no definitiion of this array in /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf file, I'm trying to figure out how to do it so the array will persist between reboots. I know USB storage is notsuitable for mission critical storage. I'm just playing around, and I guess some redundancy in my ZFS pool is better than no redundancy, until I get a second SATA HDD to attach a proper mirror.

Comment: I've created a sparate question for the md array problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/900363/mdadm-array-disappears-after-system-reboot

Answer (score 1):

To add the two new disks to the pool, you can use `zpool add tank mirror sdb sdc` but this will add the new pair as a mirror, and stripe it with the existing disk. (This doesn't add any redundancy).

You would need to use the `zpool attach` command to append the disks to the existing vdev, but you can't use a mirrored-pair to back a single disk, you would have to add a new 2TB disk to make it a mirrored pair.